# Why is the result of cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_ zone0/temp 0?

Tags: linux

I am customizing Linux and using kernel version 6.4.0. I don't know why I used `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` to check the CPU temperature and the result was `0`? But my PC is clearly starting normally and generating heat.

Did I turn off any options when `make memunconfig`?

```
# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
0
```

add type:

```
# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type
acpitz
```

================================================

I have installed the distribution version of `Debian12` on my computer and cannot access it from `thermal_zone0` can see the temperature, but it can be viewed from `thermal_zone1` sees the temperature. But my customized Linux system only has `thermal_zone0`, no `thermal_zone1`.

#1 Customized Linux system

```
# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_*
0
100000
critical
0
71000
active
0
55000
active
0
50000
active
0
45000
active
0
40000
active
```

#2 debian 12

```
# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_*
119000
critical
71000
active
55000
active
50000
active
45000
active
40000
active
# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/trip_point_*
-274000
passive
-274000
passive
# cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/type
x86_pkg_temp
```

Comment: `Did I turn off any options when make memunconfig` did you?

Comment: Since you are seeing the `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/*` virtual files, you clearly have enabled the kernel configuration option for ACPI Thermal Zones. But for some reason or another, in your specific hardware/firmware configuration, that thermal zone seems to be not used. What is the type of the thermal zone? (`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type`)

Comment: @telcoM I have added the  result of `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type`，but I couldn't find any content related to `acpitz`.

Comment: Does the temperature show up if you use a full-blown distro kernel?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I have turned off some drivers.

Comment: @StephenKitt A great troubleshooting method, I just tried it out, and the released version of Debian12 is also 0.

Comment: With the Debian kernel, what’s the type of `thermal_zone1`?

Comment: @StephenKitt  The type of `thermal_zone1` is `x86_pkg_temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at thermal zones.

The type `acpitz` is a generic ACPI thermal zone; only the developer of the ACPI firmware of your system knows for sure what it indicates, if anything.
I think there are no kernel options that would improve the output beyond what you are already seeing.

That thermal zone might be inactive in your current hardware/firmware configuration, or use a non-standard temperature scale. Either of those could explain the `0` value: if the thermal zone is actually used, it might mean something like "currently at cooling requirement level 0".

Are there any `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_*` files? If a custom scale is being used, the contents of the `trip_point_*_temp` and the respective `trip_point_*_type` values might give some idea about how the scale works.

Other possible thermal zone types include (but are not necessarily limited to) `pch_skylake` = chipset thermal sensor (of particular Intel chipsets), and `x86_pkg_temp` = CPU built-in thermal sensor. The behavior of those comes from the Linux driver retrieving the information rather than from the ACPI firmware, and so their behavior is more well known.

Comment: I have updated my issue, and strangely, when the distribution version is installed, the temperature is displayed at `thermal_zone1`.

Comment: It might be another thermal sensor, whose driver is not included in your custom kernel. What does `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/type` say? The two trip points with a value of -274000 would suggest `thermal_zone1` might be produced by the `x86_pkg_temp_thermal` module, corresponding to kernel config option `CONFIG_X86_PKG_TEMP_THERMAL`.

Comment: The type of `thermal_zone1` is `x86_pkg_temp`.

Comment: That's definitely the `x86_pkg_temp_thermal` module, then. Looks like my guess was correct.

Comment: Great, when I set `CONFIG_X86_PKG_TEMP_THERMAL=y`, I can see the temperature through `thermal_zone1`. But I'm curious why it's not `thermal_zone0`, it's `thermal_zone1`, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Because the driver for ACPI thermal zones (`CONFIG_ACPI_THERMAL`, often built into the kernel) was loaded first, and the firmware told it there is 1 ACPI thermal zone available. So the driver presented it as `thermal_zone0`. But for some reason, the system's ACPI firmware does not actually seem to produce meaningful values for it. On the other hand, `x86_pkg_temp_thermal` simply reads a few CPU registers that are clearly documented in Intel CPU datasheets, and presents the results in the form of a thermal zone, resulting in `thermal_zone1` with values that actually make sense.